# Running .exe from pyinstaller will only run the dependencies not the main script

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I am building a search GUI that has a login window followed by the main search window.

I am using `pyinstaller` to turn my python app into a `.exe`. This part works fine but when I run the `.exe`, the login window page opens as it should and when you log in it won't open the GUI search function that is part of my app, it just relaunches the login GUI.

The login is one python file and the main search window is another, it imports the login details from the login window. It is as if the exe relaunches again.

The python file works fine when running from the command prompt, I do not understand why it does not translate over to an executable.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, I can post some code if required.

I get this error message after closing the login window:

[image]

Comment: Is your script trying to install bravado dynamically? Don't do that... pyinstaller will include it as a dependency anyway.

Comment: @LukeSawczak it was actually that whole line that was unnecessary, once I removed that it worked but your comment put me on the right course thanks a mil. If you want to post an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a line in there that's apparently calling a subprocess to manually install a dependency (`bravado`).

This isn't a great idea in general — you should simply develop in a controlled environment where you know `bravado` is installed, e.g. a virtual environment in your favourite IDE.

But it's especially not needed in a build tool such as `pyinstaller`, because its job is to gather the dependencies your script needs, based on the imports, and bundle them all up into the distribution.

You can simply remove the line :)